# How do I check shortcuts for duplicates in a Qt app?

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to allow my users assign their own shortcuts for various operations. Qt offers a standard widget for this purpose, `QKeySequenceEdit`. Unfortunately, this widget does not check its input for duplicates and happily accepts even the standard combinations like `Ctrl+C` etc. What I'd like to do is:

- Ideally, get a list of all shortcuts active in my application along with their translation hints. I don't think it's possible.
- Less ideally, connect to `QKeySequenceEdit::editingFinished()`, create a shortcut and trigger it somehow to watch for the `QShortcut::activatedAmbiguously()` signal. However, there seems to be no way to trigger a shortcut programmatically.

Could of course resort to feeding the key sequence to the OS and get it played back to check for ambiguous activation, but it looks rather far-fetched. Any better ideas?

Comment: It's difficult, because not all shortcuts handled by `QShortcut` objects. Some of them handled by key press/release event handlers, so you cannot know that programmatically. Otherwise it would be easy to find all application's shortcuts with `QList<QShortcut *> sh = a.findChildren<QShortcut *>();`, where `a` is a `QApplication`.

Comment: @vahancho Could you please give a link to the `findChildren` member function template you mentioned? Can't find anything like that in Qt documentation; the `QObject::findChildren()` overloads `QApplication` inherits are not templated.

Comment: Yes, please: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren .

Comment: Oops, sorry. Thanks. My bad. I should have learned already to look at the headers first, not the online Qt documentation. :)

Comment: QtCreator does a check when you configure your shortcuts, you could have a look to their solution. My guess is all shortcuts are centralized in this *settings-datamodel* and they can do the check assuming no other shortcut will be set in the application.